# c# winrt error 0x8001010E

Tags: c#, windows-runtime

I've made a program that creates a thread and in that thread create image:

```
private async void GetCamera()
{
   ....
    tk = new Task(MyAwesomeTask);
    tk.Start();

}

private async void MyAwesomeTask()
{
        while (true)
        {
            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5));
            SavePhoto1();
        }
}

private  void SavePhoto1()
{
        try
        {
            WriteableBitmap wb1 = new WriteableBitmap(320, 240);//throw exception
        }catch (Exception ee)
        {
            String s = ee.ToString();
        }

}
```

But line

```
WriteableBitmap wb1 = new WriteableBitmap(320, 240);
```

throws exception:

> s="System.Exception: The application called an interface that was marshalled for a different thread. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8001010E (RPC_E_WRONG_THREAD))\r\n   at Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging.WriteableBitmap..ctor(Int32 pixelWidth, Int32 pixelHeight)\r\n   at TestVideo.MainPage.SetImageFromStream() in ...\MainPage.xaml.cs:line 500\r\n   at TestVideo.MainPage.SavePhoto1() in ....\MainPage.xaml.cs:line 145"

What I need to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first problem is that you are using `async void`. The only time that you should do this is when the method is an event handler.  In your case, you should use `async Task` instead:

```
private async Task GetCamera()
{
   ....
    //tk = new Task(MyAwesomeTask);
    //tk.Start();
    await Task.Run(async () => await MyAwesomeTask());
    ...    
}

private async Task MyAwesomeTask()
{
    while (true)
    {
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5));
        // added await
        await SavePhoto1();
    }
}
```

You do not actually need to return a `Task` in the above methods. The compiler automagically does that for you.

To address your question, you should only create `WriteableBitmap` objects on the UI thread.  You can do so with this:

```
private async Task SavePhoto1()
{
    try
    {
        WriteableBitmap wb1 = null;
        await ExecuteOnUIThread(() =>
        {
            wb1 = new WriteableBitmap(320, 240);//throw exception
        });

        // do something with wb1 here
        wb1.DoSomething();
    }catch (Exception ee)
    {
        String s = ee.ToString();
    }
}    

public static IAsyncAction ExecuteOnUIThread(Windows.UI.Core.DispatchedHandler action)
{
    return Windows.ApplicationModel.Core.CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, action);
}
```

I didn't test the above by compiling it, but it should give you a good start. Let me know if you have questions.